# Does the upgrade to OS X Lion include iMovie 11?

Tags: macos, imovie

I have a system with Snow Leopard and iMovie 09.

If I upgrade my system to OSX Lion, will it also upgrade my iMovie 09 to iMovie 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, iMovie is part of the iLife suite of programs, not the OS itself. It's only included bundled with the OS when you buy a new Mac.

Comment: iMovie 11 is available on the Mac App Store (for $15).  It says it only requires 10.6.7, so upgrading your iMovie and OS X should be completely independent.